# If statement is not printing out on my system call

Tags: c, system-calls

I input age as 30 but its not printing my if statement. Can i know why ? Thanks

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 512

int main()
{
    int a;
    char *buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    
    write(1,"Please Enter your age: ",23);
    a=read(0,*buffer,100);
    
    if(a>21)
    write(1,"You are an adult",16);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to flush or add a newline. Also to do a similar but different output in the `else`.

Comment: Try using `stdio` i.e. `fgets` - This line requires 100 characters - `a=read(0,*buffer,100);`

Comment: `buffer` was declared as an array of `512` pointers to `char`. Not the program intention...

Answer (score 1):

This

```
char *buffer[BUFFSIZE];
```

declares an array of uninitialized pointers.

This

```
a=read(0,*buffer,100);
```

passes the first uninitialized pointer to `read`, so almost certain returns an error (probably EFAULT).

If you were to fix that (remove the `*` from both lines), it would still return 3 if you enter <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard (3 characters entered)

---

Fixing all that, you end up with something like:

```
int main() {
    int len;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    write(1,"Please Enter your age: ",23);
    len=read(0,buffer,BUFSIZE-1);
    if (len <= 0) {
        write(1, "invalid input", 13);
    } else {
        buffer[len] = '\0';
        char *end;
        int age = strtol(buffer, &end, 0);
        if (*end != '\n')
            write(1, "input not a (just) a number", 27);
        if(age > 21)
            write(1,"You are an adult",16);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There's more stuff you can do with error checking (for example, you might want to ignore spaces on the end of the line, or other questionable input), but this shows where to start.

Comment: ... In addition the `read` does not stop at the new line. But carries on waiting for extra data

Comment: hi thanks i remove * from both lines. It working as you said it only capture 3 instead of 30 , how can i fix that

Comment: @EdHeal: read returns as soon as at least one byte has been read when there are no bytes left in the input buffer.  It will *never* wait when there is some data to return.  For a terminal in line mode (the usual case), this will read up to the newline and return just that.

Comment: @Noobies It captures what you type in `buffer` and returns how many charaters were read.  If you want to convert those characters to a number, you can use `strtol(buffer, 0, 0)`

Comment: @ChrisDodd sorry im confused , can you show me what my full code looks like to capture the correct input ?

Comment: @ChrisDodd - Are you sure about that? Had a quick look for the documentation that describes this behaviour from reading from a file descriptor. Perhaps you can give me a reference

Comment: @EdHeal: yes, I'm sure -- its implicit from the description on the [read man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/read.html)

Comment: `int age = strtol(buffer, &end, 0);` - Buffer may not be null terminated

Comment: @ChrisDodd - I will do some experiments tomorrow. Not convinced with "implicit"

Comment: @EdHeal: There's some relevant info [here](https://www.linuxtoday.com/blog/blocking-and-non-blocking-i-0/), talking about 'fast' and 'slow' file descriptor types.

Answer (score 0):

If you consult the [documentation for `read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) you will see that the return value is the *number of bytes read*.  You will need to read the characters in `buffer` and convert them from a string to an `int` instead of doing what you are doing.

The C standard library provides functions like `atoi` and `scanf` that you can use to convert the string into a number, but it's pretty easy to do it yourself and it's a good exercise for a new C programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, which changes read for more commonly used fscanf:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    
    write(1,"Please Enter your age: ",23);
    fscanf(stdin, "%d",&a);
    if(a>21)
    write(1,"You are an adult",16);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, but my question forced me to use only read and write system call